# What is value of this integral? $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\log(1+4x^2)(1+9x^2)(9+x^2)+(9+x^2)\log(4+x^2)(10+10x^2)}{(9+x^2)^{2}(1+9x^{2})}dx$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, improper-integrals

> What is value of this integral $$I=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\log(1+4x^2)(1+9x^2)(9+x^2)+(9+x^2)\log(4+x^2)(10+10x^2)}{(9+x^2)^{2}(1+9x^2)}dx$$

My work :
\begin{align*}I&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\log(1+4x^2)}{9+x^2}dx+\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\log(4+x^2)(10+10x^2)}{(9+x^2)(1+9x^2)}dx\\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\log(1+4x^2)}{9+x^2}dx+\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\log(4+x^2)}{1+9x^2}dx+\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\log(4+x^2)}{9+x^2}dx\\
&=j_{1}+j_{2}+j_{3}\\
\end{align*}
$$j_{1}=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\log(1+4x^2)}{9+x^2}dx=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n(2^{2(n+1)})}{n+1}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2(n+1)}}{9+x^2}dx$$ 
$$j_{2}=\log(4)\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{1+(3x)^2}dx+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n}}{(n+1)(2^{2(n+1)})}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2(n+1)}}{1+9x^2}dx=\frac{\log(4)\pi}{6}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(n+1)2^{2(n+1)}}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2(n+1)}}{1+9x^2}dx$$
$$j_{3}=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\log(4+x^2)}{9+x^2}dx=\frac{\log(4)\pi}{54}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(n+1)2^{2(n+1)}}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2(n+1)}}{9+x^2}dx$$
Wait for a review to find solutions to this

Comment: Try `\underbrace{your integral}_{j_1}`.

Comment: Using the beta function, but I also reached more deadlocks than the calculation directly, I will try again

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Consider using differentiation under the integral sign.  Parameterize the integral as the following:
$$I(a)=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\ln{\left(1+ax^2\right)}}{9+x^2} + \frac{\ln{\left(a+x^2\right)}}{1+9x^2}+ \frac{\ln{\left(a+x^2\right)}}{9+x^2} \; \mathrm{d}x$$
The integral in question is $I(4)$.  First, differentiate $I(a)$ with respect to $a$: \begin{align*}
I'(a)&=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^2}{(9+x^2)(1+ax^2)}+\frac{1}{(1+9x^2)(a+x^2)}+\frac{1}{(9+x^2)(a+x^2)} \; \mathrm{d}x \\
&=\int_0^{\infty} -\frac{10 (a - 1)}{(a - 9) (9 a - 1) (a + x^2)} + \frac{2 (9 a - 41)}{(a - 9) (9 a - 1) (x^2 + 9)} + \frac{9}{(9 a - 1) (9 x^2 + 1)} + \frac{1}{(1 - 9 a) (a x^2 + 1)} \; \mathrm{d}x \\
&=\frac{\pi}{6} \left(\frac{\frac{19}{\sqrt{a}}+9}{3a+10\sqrt{a}+3}\right)\\
\end{align*}
Now, $I'(a)$ with respect to $a$ from $0$ to $4$:
\begin{align*}
I(4)&=\frac{\pi}{6} \int_0^4 \frac{\frac{19}{\sqrt{a}}+9}{3a+10\sqrt{a}+3} \; \mathrm{d}a \\
&=\frac{\pi}{6} \int_0^4 \frac{\frac{1}{\sqrt{a}}}{\sqrt{a}+3} + \frac{\frac{6}{\sqrt{a}}}{3\sqrt{a}+1} \; \mathrm{d} a \\
&=\frac{\pi}{6} \left(2 \int_0^4 \frac{\mathrm{d}\left(\sqrt{a}+3\right)}{\sqrt{a}+3} +  4 \int_0^4 \frac{\mathrm{d}\left(3\sqrt{a}+1\right)}{3\sqrt{a}+1}\right) \\
&=\frac{\pi}{3} \left(\ln{\left(\sqrt{a}+3\right)}+2\ln{\left(3\sqrt{a}+1\right)}\right) \bigg \rvert_0^4 \\
I(4) &= \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\log(1+4x^2)(1+9x^2)(9+x^2)+(9+x^2)\log(4+x^2)(10+10x^2)}{(9+x^2)^{2}(1+9x^2)} \mathrm{d}x =\boxed{\frac{\pi \ln{\left(\frac{245}{3}\right)}}{3}}\\
\end{align*}

Comment: Randomly getting 5 down votes nearly 2 weeks after posting this..?  There is nothing wrong with this answer.  Any down voter care to explain what's wrong with this answer?  This isn't my only post that has been recently wrongfully mass down voted a while after posting it...

Answer (score 6):

First, the integral:

$$
I := \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\ln\left(1+4\,x^2\right)\left(1+9\,x^2\right)\left(9+\,x^2\right)+\left(9+x^2\right)\ln\left(4+x^2\right)\left(10+10\,x^2\right)}{\left(9+x^2\right)^2\left(1+9\,x^2\right)}\,\text{d}x
$$

thanks to the *linearity of the integrals* it can be written as the algebraic sum of two integrals:

$$
I = 
\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\ln\left(1+4\,x^2\right)}{9+x^2}\,\text{d}x + 
\int_0^{\infty} \frac{10\left(1+x^2\right)\ln\left(4 + x^2\right)}{\left(9+\,x^2\right)\left(1+9\,x^2\right)}\,\text{d}x\,.
$$

At this point, to calculate the first, it's sufficient to consider the function $J : [0,\,+\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ of the law:

$$
J(a) := \int_0^{\infty} \frac{\ln\left(1+a\,x^2\right)}{9+x^2}\,\text{d}x
$$

whose first derivative is equal to:

$$
J'(a) = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^2}{\left(9+x^2\right)\left(1+a\,x^2\right)}\,\text{d}x = \frac{\pi}{2\left(\sqrt{a}+3\,a\right)}
$$

and therefore, going back, we get:

$$
J(a) = \int \frac{\pi}{2\left(\sqrt{a}+3\,a\right)}\,\text{d}a = \frac{\pi}{3}\,\ln\left(1 + 3\sqrt{a}\right) + c
$$

where equaling the two expressions of $J(0)$ must be $c = 0$, from which:

$$
\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\ln\left(1+a\,x^2\right)}{9+x^2}\,\text{d}x = \frac{\pi}{3}\,\ln\left(1 + 3\sqrt{a}\right).
$$

Similarly, to calculate the second, it's sufficient to consider the function $K : [0,\,+\infty) \to \mathbb{R}$ of the law:

$$
K(b) := \int_0^{\infty} \frac{10\left(1+x^2\right)\ln\left(4 + b\,x^2\right)}{\left(9+\,x^2\right)\left(1+9\,x^2\right)}\,\text{d}x
$$

whose first derivative is equal to:

$$
K'(b) = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{10\,x^2\left(1+x^2\right)}{\left(9+x^2\right)\left(1+9\,x^2\right)\left(4+b\,x^2\right)}\,\text{d}x = \frac{\left(3+\frac{10}{\sqrt{b}}\right)\pi}{3\left(12+20\sqrt{b}+3\,b\right)}
$$

and therefore, going back, we get:

$$
K(b) = \int \frac{\left(3+\frac{10}{\sqrt{b}}\right)\pi}{3\left(12+20\sqrt{b}+3\,b\right)}\,\text{d}b = \frac{\pi}{3}\,\ln\left(12+20\sqrt{b}+3\,b\right) + c
$$

where equaling the two expressions of $K(0)$ must be $c = \frac{2\,\pi}{3}\,\ln(2) - \frac{\pi}{3}\,\ln(12)$, from which:

$$
\int_0^{\infty} \frac{10\left(1+x^2\right)\ln\left(4 + b\,x^2\right)}{\left(9+\,x^2\right)\left(1+9\,x^2\right)}\,\text{d}x = \frac{\pi}{3}\,\ln\left(12+20\sqrt{b}+3\,b\right) + \frac{2\,\pi}{3}\,\ln(2) - \frac{\pi}{3}\,\ln(12)\,.
$$

In conclusion, setting $a = 4$ and $b = 1$, we get:

$$
I = \frac{\pi}{3}\,\ln\left(1 + 3\sqrt{4}\right) + \frac{\pi}{3}\,\ln\left(12+20\sqrt{1}+3\cdot 1\right) + \frac{2\,\pi}{3}\,\ln(2) - \frac{\pi}{3}\,\ln(12) = \frac{\pi}{3}\,\ln\left(\frac{245}{3}\right),
$$

which is what is desired.

Answer (score 4):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
With $\ds{a,b,c \in \mathbb{R}_{\ >\ 0}}$:
\begin{align}
\mrm{f}\pars{a,b,c} & \equiv
\int_{0}^{\infty}{\ln\pars{a^{2} + b^{2}x^{2}} \over c^{2} + x^{2}}\,\dd x =
\Re\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\ln\pars{a + bx\ic} \over
\pars{x + c\ic}\pars{x - c\ic}}\,\dd x
\end{align}
With the change
$\ds{\pars{x = -\,{s - a \over b}\,\ic \implies s = a + bx\ic}}$:
\begin{align}
\mrm{f}\pars{a,b,c} & =
-\,\Im\int_{a - \infty\ic}^{a + \infty\ic}{b\ln\pars{s} \over
\bracks{s - \pars{a - bc}}\bracks{s - \pars{a + bc}}}\,\dd s
\\[5mm] & =
-\,\Im\bracks{-2\pi\ic\,{b\ln\pars{a + bc} \over 2bc}} =
\bbx{\pi\,{\ln\pars{a + bc} \over c}} \\ & 
\end{align}

---

$$
\left\{\begin{array}{rcccccl}
\ds{j_{1}} & \ds{=} &
\ds{\int_{0}^{\infty}{\ln\pars{1 + 4x^{2}} \over 9 + x^{2}}\,\dd x}
& \ds{=} & \ds{\mrm{f}\pars{1,2,3}} & \ds{=} & \ds{{\pi \over 3}\ln\pars{7}}
\\[2mm]
\ds{j_{2}} & \ds{=} &
\ds{\int_{0}^{\infty}{\ln\pars{4 + x^{2}} \over 1 + 9x^{2}}\,\dd x}
& \ds{=} & \ds{{1 \over 9}\,\mrm{f}\pars{2,1,{1 \over 3}}} & \ds{=} & \ds{{\pi \over 3}\,\ln\pars{7 \over 3}}
\\[2mm]
\ds{j_{3}} & \ds{=} &
\ds{\int_{0}^{\infty}{\ln\pars{4 + x^{2}} \over 9 + x^{2}}\,\dd x}
& \ds{=} & \ds{\mrm{f}\pars{2,1,3}} & \ds{=} 
& \ds{{\pi \over 3}\,\ln\pars{5}}
\end{array}\right.
$$
\begin{align}
\mbox{} &
\\
j_{1} + j_{2} + j{3} & =
\bbx{{1 \over 3}\,\pi\ln\pars{245 \over 3}} \approx 4.6104 \\ &
\end{align}